# ngrx effect not firing action

Tags: node.js, angular, ngrx

I have an issue with ngrx. Inside an Effect, I call a Backend route in NodeJS, as such:

```
@Effect() 
authSignup = this.actions$ 
    .ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNUP)
    .switchMap((action: AuthActions.TrySignup) => { 
        return this.httpClient.post('nodejs_backend_route') 
        .map((response: any) => { 
            return Observable.of({ type: AuthActions.SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP }); 
        })
    });
```

If the route inside `.post` is a Backend route in NodeJS, the action fired inside `.map` is not recognized. I get this error:

`“Error: Effect "AuthEffects.authSignup" dispatched an invalid action: [object Object]”`

Yet the action `AuthActions.SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP` exists. If no call to the Backend is made, the action fires perfectly. Is there an issue with making calls to a NodeJS Backend from inside an ngrx Effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
@Effect()
authSignup$: Observable<AuthActions.All> = this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofType<AuthActions.TrySignup>(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNUP),
    switchMap((action) => this.httpClient.post('nodejs_backend_route')
      .pipe(
        map((response) => new AuthActions.SuccessfulSignup(response)),
        catchError((error) => of(new AuthActions.FailedSignup(error)))
      )
    )
  );
```

Problem is you are not returning a `Action` in your `map`. I have rewrote it to give you a hint how it could be done with the latest versions of vendors.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution is perfect! Where did you get the idea of using pipes? I haven't seen that anywhere in ngrx tutorials. I've yet to understand how exactly this works with those pipes.

Comment: Pipes and importing of the operators changed from RxJs 5.5. Look into https://www.learnrxjs.io documentation. Don't forget to accept my answer and upvote ;)

Comment: I accepted and upvoted. I heard about this change in RxJS 5.5, but didn't think that is where my problem is. In fact, I managed to rework your solution but without using pipes at all! Thanks again!

Comment: Yop, it isn't in the pipes, as I said, problem was that you didn't return a new Action, but a basic observable with a `type` property.

Comment: Hi Kamil, I had another question. Suppose I need to fire several new actions instead of just one inside the map. Can the method above still work? If I do:

`map((response) => {
    new AuthActions.SuccessfulSignup(response))
    new AuthActions.AnotherType(response))
}`

I get Action invalid errors.

Comment: Nope. you need to use `mergeMap`.

Comment: Thanks, so I have:
`this.httpClient.post(...)
.mergeMap(...)
.catchError(...)`

Comment: Yop, and mergeMap takes an array of actions.